# Gmail with OAuth: How to access the users mailbox on behalf of the user?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

As Google does not support "client_credentials" grant in OAuth, how can I access the users mailbox on behalf of him (machine to machine)?

My Java application would be able to store any user credentials in a secure place.

Thanks for a pointer :)

***UPDATE***

Thank you for your response. But I am not sure, if this explanation solves my use case. Let me better describe the environment:

Since several years, I have a background Java task which runs without user interventions:

- The user enters once his normal username and password credentials which are saved in a secure place.
- The Java task regularly connect (thru IMAP) to the users mail box (e.g. john.doe@gmail.com) thru the Java Jakarta Mail API to read and process any new incoming mail from the users inbox.

To support a more modern authentication, I would like to switch the authentication to OAuth 2.0. The used Jakarta Mail API already support the IMAP connect thru the use of an access token, so I only need to add the code to ask the authorisation server for the access token.

Questions:

- Is this possible with Google OAuth?
- Which OAuth grant type must be used? First I thought "client_credentials" should be used, but Google do not currently seem to support it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) lets you do that:

> In Google Workspace domains, the domain administrator can grant third-party applications with domain-wide access to its users' data — this is known as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0.

This is obviously a very powerful capability, so make sure to:

- [protect the service account appropriately](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-securing-service-accounts)
- only grant the least set of OAuth scopes that's necessary.

Note that domain-wide delegation [doesn't necessarily require service account keys](https://jpassing.com/2022/01/15/using-domain-wide-delegation-on-google-cloud-without-service-account-keys/).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to update my question to better describe it.